# Any CDNs that allow custom HTTP headers?

Tags: http, http-headers, cdn

I'm looking for a CDN that will allow the addition of these into the header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: url");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with');
```

Max budget:$60/Month
,Specifics: Well spread data centers, hopefully some in Asia too as the load times there are particularly slow.
I've looked at previous threads here, to no avail though. They don't really list any viable CDNs as much as they do discuss how to achieve the HTTP additions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

MaxCDN has a product called EdgeRules. You can modify all headers.